# Python 3.4 Sockets sendall function

Tags: function, sockets, python-3.x, client

```
import socket

def functions():
    print ("hello")


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_address = ('192.168.137.1', 20000)
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()
print ('Connected by', addr)

sock.listen(1)
conn.sendall(b"Welcome to the server")
```

My question is how to send a function to the client,
I know that conn.sendall(b"Welcome to the server") will data to the client.
Which can be decoded.

I would like to know how to send a function to a client like
conn.sendall(function()) - this does not work

Also I would like to know the function that would allow the client to receive the function I am sending

I have looked on the [python website](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) for a function that could do this but I have not found one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality requested by you is principally impossible unless explicitly coded on client side. If this were possible, one could write a virus which easily spreads into any remote machine. Instead, this is client right responsibility to decode incoming data in any manner.

Considering a case client really wants to receive a code to execute, the issue is that code shall be represented in a form which, at the same time,

- is detached from server context and its specifics, and can be serialized and executed at any place
- allows secure execution in a kind of sandbox, because a very rare client will allow arbitrary server code to do anything at the client side.

The latter is extremely complex topic; you can read any WWW browser security history - most of closed vulnerabilities are of issues in such sandboxing.

(There are environments when such execution is allowed and desired; e.g. Erlang cookie-based peering cluster. But, in such cluster, side B is also allowed to execute anything at side A.)

You should start with searching an execution environment (high-level virtual machine) which conforms to your needs in functionality and security. For Python, you'd look at `multiprocessing` module: its implementation of worker pools doesn't pass the code itself, but simplifies passing data for execution requests. Also, passing of arbitrary Python data without functions is covered with `marshal` and `pickle` modules.